# $\partial(S') \subset \partial S$ iff $S' \cap S^o \subset (S')^o$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Usually I can come up with some ideas but this time I don't. It would be great if you can tell me how I would make use of the first part of the question to prove the equivalent relation.

Question:

> Let $X$ be a metric space and $S$ be a subset of $X$. Prove that $(S ')' \subset S' $. Hence, prove that $\partial(S') \subset \partial S$ iff $S' \cap S^o \subset (S')^o$.

I now define the following:

- $S'$ : the derived set of S, i.e. the set containing all the accumulation points of S
- $\partial S$ : the boundary of S, i.e. the set containing all the boundary points of S
- $S^o$ : the interior of S, i.e. the set containing all the interior points of S

Here is what I proved for the first part of the question.
Let $x \in (S ')'$. For any $r>0$, $B(x,r) \cap S'\setminus \{x\} \neq \emptyset$.
It implies that there exists $y \in X$ such that $y \in B(x,r)$ and $y \in S'\setminus \{x\}$. Then, define $s = \frac{1}{2} (r- d(x,y))$. Clearly, $B(y,s) \subset B(x,r)$. Note that $\#\{B(y,s) \cap S \setminus \{x\}\} = \infty$. It implies $x \in S'$.

Please feel free to comment on my proof above and give me any ideas on the second part of the question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the forward direction, assume that $\partial ( S' ) \subseteq \partial S$. Suppose that $x \in S' \cap S^\circ$ does not belong to $(S')^\circ$. This means that every open neighbourhood of $x$ contains a point which does not belong to $S'$. As $x \in S'$, it follows that $x \in \partial(S') \subseteq \partial S$, contradicting that $x$ is an interior point of $S$.

For the backwards direction, assume that $S' \cap S^\circ \subseteq ( S' )^\circ$. Suppose that $x \in \partial(S')$. As $\partial A \subseteq A'$ for all $A \subseteq X$, it follows that $\partial ( S' ) \subseteq ( S' )' \subseteq S'$, and so $x \in S'$: every open neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $S$.  On the other hand, note that $\partial (A) \cap A^\circ = \varnothing$ for all $A \subseteq X$, and so it must be that $x \notin ( S' )^\circ$. As $x \in S'$ by our assumption it must be that $x \notin S^\circ$: every open neighbourhood of $x$ contains a point not belonging to $S$.  Therefore $x \in \partial S$.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understand most of your proof but can you kindly explain the sentence 'As $x \in S'$ by our assumption it must be that $x \notin S^\circ$'?

Comment: @LeeKM: Since $x \in \partial(S')$ and $\partial ( S' ) \cap (S')^\circ = \varnothing$ it must be that $x \notin (S')^\circ$. Since $x \in S'$ and $x \notin (S')^\circ$, our assumption that $S' \cap S^\circ \subseteq (S')^\circ$ implies that $x \notin S^\circ$ (otherwise $x \in S' \cap S^\circ \subseteq (S')^\circ$, which we know is false).